# How to Read Java List Object in XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am having a Java Object which is ArrayList and i have added it in response of service which is in XML format as below,

```
<root>
<SubRoot>
<type>A</type>
<mand>Y</mand>
<Section>B</Section>
</SubRoot>
<SubRoot>
<type>A</type>
<mand>Y</mand>
<Section>A</Section>
</SubRoot>
</root>
```

I am trying to use the some value from above xml for condition.On basis of true condition i will call some template for my purpose.

I am calling my xsl template as below,

```
<xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="(/root/SubRoot[Section = 'A'])">
    //Call some template 
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    //some template
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="(/root/SubRoot[Section = 'B'])">
    //call some template
    </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
//some template
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Each time my first `when` will get executed its not coming inside the second `when` condition.

Could you please help me how the both condition will get executed?is it right approach in terms of performance?

Any Suggestion approach must be appreciated.

Comment: Use two `xsl:if test` instead of a single `xsl:choose/xsl:when` to fix that. Using template matching might ease the task with XSLT but you haven't provided enough details to tell.

Comment: Martin I have also tried with two if and this xsl code block is in two independent xsl choose.If I will use template matching will it cause performance issue?how can I use this with template matching.could you please suggest me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: First of all, I suggest you post a minimal yet valid version of your XSL which is prooved to be failing. For example: The `when` nodes are wrongly closed: The misss the `xsl`namespace.

Comment: And, when I test your XSL (basically fulfilled to get a complete XSL) against the posted XML, but conditions are satisfied and the respective templates are called.

Comment: Little Santi thanks.Could you please let me know is it right approach to  get the value from XML in context of performance ?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SubRoot">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Section = 'A'">
            <!-- your logic for A -->
            <A></A>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- your logic for B -->
            <B></B>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

XML

```
<root>
<SubRoot>
    <type>A</type>
    <mand>Y</mand>
    <Section>B</Section>
</SubRoot>
<SubRoot>
    <type>A</type>
    <mand>Y</mand>
    <Section>A</Section>
</SubRoot>
```

Demo link : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/15